# Assign permanent drive name to USB (across different computers)?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, shortcuts

Some of the shortcuts on my flash drive need the drive to be assigned to a specific name, and I need to access this across several computers. Is there a way that the flash drive's drive name can be set to one so that this will work for any computer that this drive will be plugged into? Alternatively, can I make a shortcut without use of a drive name?

Comment: You cannot guarantee a particular drive letter will be free on any machine so in short no. Forcing a drive letter to be mapped could create conflicts with mapped drives as well. Windows natively will not allow you to make relative shortcuts either which would have been nice. Is this really what you want to know? What issue are you trying to solve? BAT,CMD and VBS files will allow you to use relative pathing so that could be a solution. Or use a utility like PStart on your key that would be called before your exe/utilities

Comment: I am using a .bat file. And if I name it something like X: then imo I doubt it would be taken :) So is there a way to do it ignoring the fact that the drive name might  be taken? It sounds childish, but it *would* be cool to have my flash drive assigned to X: :)
Also, I assigned a permanent drive letter through Disk Management on my computer and the drive just got a new name (on the same computer). WHAT IS THIS